# LSV model calibration with only few quotes per maturity

Tags: fx, stochastic-volatility, calibration, local-volatility, volatility-smile

At [this link](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/44437/what-is-market-standard-model-in-equity-fx-and-interest-rates-exotics/44438#44438) I have asked what is the market standard when pricing options in different asset classes. Based on the answers, the standard for FX and equities seems to be the local-stochastic volatility models. 
My question is how can such a model be calibrated in practice for FX. The reason why I mention FX specifically is that I can see that only 3 strikes are quoted in the market (those embedded in the ATM straddle and in the 25 delta risk reversal and butterfly). If also the 10 delta are quoted, there are 5 quotes. 
But how can that be enough to successfully calibrate on a FX surface? 
Is there any example that shows how to calibrate, for example, Heston local volatility model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [this paper](https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=2448098).

This is a rather exhaustive paper summarizing 9 models to be used as Local-Stochastic Volatility (LSV) models.

It describes various aspects of Calibration and Pricing of LSV models with the associated references, so that you can dig deeper in the topic should you find a suitable model for your needs.

The beginning of the abstract goes as follows:

> We analyze in detail calibration and pricing performed within the
>   framework of local stochastic volatility LSV models, which have become
>   the industry market standard for FX and equity markets. We present the
>   main arguments for the need of having such models, and address the
>   question whether jumps have to be included. We include a comprehensive
>   literature overview, and focus our exposition on important details
>   related to calibration procedures and option pricing using PDEs or
>   PIDEs derived from LSV models.

Comment: Thanks, but is there something to show the application to FX surfaces where only few strikes are traded?

Comment: I think Uwe Wystup did some work on this. Have a look at `The Simplified Formula` paragraph on page 16 of https://mathfinance.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/CPQF_Arbeits20_neu2.pdf. If I remember, he uses only 3 anchor points to calibrate the volatility smile.

Comment: But this is not in the context of local stochastic volatility right?

Comment: I am mostly curious how the actual calibration on FX does not suffer from the fact that only few strikes or deltas are available at a given time

Comment: I see. Then have a look at the robustness of Local Volatility (LV) and Stochastic Volatility (SV) (i.e. Heston) models against scarce data separately. Then, as the LSV can be seen as some "weighted-average" of LV and SV, you could introduce some weight factor in order to gear your model towards the one which performs best against scarce data.

Comment: In a previous question (link in the opening post) a user said that in practice there is an initial smoothing that is performed on the raw data you get from Bloomberg. Something like: get the quotes then interpolate/smooth with SVI (or Vanna Volga in FX) and finally calibrate Heston/LV/LSV on the smoothed/interpolated data. I was wondering if this approach is somehow documented in some paper/book so that I can get an idea of the exact way to proceed. .

Comment: Sure, the key is to have a smoothed implied volatility surface before proceeding with both Heston and Local Vol (and further LSV). SVI copes well with scarce data, you can have a look at the main references on the topic via Google.

Comment: But there is no reference I can use to see how the process would work from A to Z? Cause in all the documents I read so far they never mention this preliminary SVI smoothing. And to me sounds a bit bizarre that we then try to calibrate a model on interpolated data (which might be already not a true representation of real market data).

Comment: Ok, take Dupire's formula for instance: you need to know the price of your options at any couple (T,K), with T and K being the time to maturity and the strike. To do so, since you only observe particular options, hence particular couples (Ti,Ki), you need an interpolation method to compute the local volatility function at T,K.

Comment: Yes I understand the need in the context of LV. But more in general, if an interpolation method is not good enough in the tails (like for example SVI, Maltz, vanna volga, sabr that have very flat smile for lower/higher strikes), whatever fancy model we calibrate to these interpolated data afterwards, say a LSV, will still provide a flat smile in the tails, no? This is what is confusing me and why I wanted to read if the whole process (best practice) is described somehow to see how these problems are fixed.

Comment: I see. I think this requires a new post then, namely about fitting an implied volatility smile in the tail :)

Comment: @opt It's a good point that it makes no sense to calibrate a model on a smooth smile that is arbitrageable. There are version(s) of SVI that do guarantee an arb-free smoothed smile. Google is your friend (sometimes) :)

Comment: You could directly model the local vol and use the forward Dupire PDE.